# location name of a position for a weather app

Tags: java, android, geolocation, google-geocoder

i want to build a weather app and i have some problems.
my big problems is places names! you know, i want that user find his location with two ways. with GPS and by searching. but my problem is that place names. how can find a database from whole places in the world?!

is it good idea that i store them in a database in my server? or there is some services that provide this functionality? if i have to create my own database how i can create a database like that. is there a database with city names and latitude/ longitude and other information? if a new location created how i can add it to the system? by hand?

the second problem is that after catching the city name how i can find that locations latitude/ longitude? it seems google has a Geocoder service but i don't know how it works. please help me. i just want to select a city  name and find related coordinates...

Comment: Did you read the description in google-geocoder tag? It gives a pointer on where you should look.

Answer (score 1):

**The Google Maps API provides you with Geocoding**, which allows you to turn strings like 'Santiago, Chile' or 'New York', into proper latitude/longitude coordinates. So in your code, you should perform an HTTP GET request to a URL like this one:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Santiago,+Chile&sensor=true
```

And it returns a JSON object with a properly formatted address along with latitude and longitude information of the place you were looking up.

It's explained very thoroughly in [**the Google Maps API Geocoder documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding), so you should probably take a look at that. I'm no expert in Android development, but there should be some library that allows you to easily access what the Maps API has to offer in a clean way.

Maps API also provides you with **a solution for Place Searching**, and even input autocompletion, but all the examples I see are on JavaScript/HTML, so I'm not completely sure if there's an alternative in plain Java/Android to what you're trying to do. Nevertheless, you should take a look at [**basic place searching**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) and [**place search autocompletion**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) so you get a general sense of how it works.

There's [**an entire section in the Google Developers website dedicated to the Maps API on Android**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), so make sure to take a look at that aswell and you might find more useful information - sadly I have no experience with Android whatsoever so I can't really point you in any direction.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Google Maps Geocoding API. Querying coordinates returns a JSON response containing the current location in multiple levels of detail that you could parse.

E.g. for the position lat:40.714224 long: -73.961452, the query URL would look like the following:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

The result now contains the city and country, beside much more.

You can find more information on the API here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: thanks but when if i want to search, how i can find locations? for example imagine i have a Autocomlplete EditText and i want to search my current city and i expect that shows some result for me and i choose one of them. for this, what i have to do?

Comment: So, you want to know the time offset for those cities? I am not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: ok, i explain it clearly. i want to search a city name and when i find it, when i click on that, i catch it's latitude and longitude. just this. i want that all of places in the world can be searchable. for this there is an API from google or other sources? or i have to create my own database of city names of whole world?!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try http://openweathermap.org/

I haven't used this extensively but I tried it enough that I know it works. It lets you query by location name or geographic coordinates, and the city name is included in the responses along with plenty of other data.

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=xx&lon=xx returns a weather object with city name & related data. API key is even optional so you can try it out very quickly.